# How can I get rid of this little line in my image ? (CSS3 , hover on effect)

Tags: html, css, animation, hover, effect

I have a problem. Im fairly new to web design. I'm making a site with little images of doors that appear opened when I mouse hover on them. They will later contain links.

the code is

```
<table><tr><td background="usa-inchisa2.png" height="232px" width="181px" id="usa"></td> </tr>
```

and I have an external css :

```
#usa {
background-image: url('usa-inchisa2.png');
height:223px;
width :181px;
}

#usa:hover {
background-image: url('usa-deschisa2.png');
```

When I hover on I get this:

[image]

There is sort of residual line at the bottom of the image. I don't know where it comes from. At one point I managed to remove it but I can't remember what I did. Does it have anything to do with the table border?
Can you help me please? Thank you

Comment: Use CSS for backgrounds, not cell attributes.

Comment: In fact, since you're using tables for layout instead of tabular data, you really should just switch away from tables entirely. You can use the [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) CSS property (with values of `table`, `table-cell`, `table-row`, etc.) to keep the same layout effect without having semantically incorrect markup.

Comment: Do you have a JSFiddle or Plunk?

Comment: As @Marcin said: images in backgrounds are set to repeat by default. If the image is 100px in height and the container is 105px you'll see 5px from the next repetition of the image.

Comment: And as @Deekey exemplified resizing the container to the size of the image is also a solution. But you can use `no-repeat` even when you know the container *has* to be bigger that the image size.

Answer (score 1):

Although I agree with @ajp15243 , I would solve your problem by trying this:

```
#usa {
background-image: url('usa-inchisa2.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
height:223px;
width :181px;
}

#usa:hover {
background-image: url('usa-deschisa2.png');
```

As you probably notice, I put "background-repeat" to "no-repeat". This is because it looks like you have more than one image at that screenshot. And the image you're having problems with is a couple of pixels smaller than the rest of the images. Since the height of a table row by default is the same for all cells in that row, the background image is repeated in the Y axis.

Answer (score 0):

Please Use this CSS

```
#usa {
background-image: url('usa-inchisa2.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
height:223px;
width :179px;
}
```